# I have to write a procedure to select the details of the vehicle where the vehicle number is given as input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the schema as vehicle(vehicle_no,engine_no,offence_count,license_status,owner_no);
I created a new table similar to that of table vehicle using the query

`create table vehi as select * from vehicle where 1=2;`

I tried using the procedure as

`create or replace procedure dispvehicle(num in number)
begin
select * into vehi from vehicle where vehicle_no=num;
end;
/`

But this procedure displayed an error saying

```
"3/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/15     PLS-00403: expression 'VEHI' cannot be used as an INTO-target of
         a SELECT/FETCH statement

3/20     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier"
```

Can you please help me with this problem.

Comment: `select ... INTO <name>` will save the output of the `select` statement into a variable in your procedure - it will not insert into a table in your database. If the homework assignment is to use PL/SQL to insert into a table, you need an INSERT ... SELECT ... statement (no need for variables). If you MUST use a record variable, you must define it first, then populate it with the SELECT ... INTO ... statement, and then insert the record into the new table.

Comment: Change your select statement to `INSERT into vehi select * from vehicle where vehicle_no=num`

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert data in a table like you did.
Try with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dispvehicle (num IN NUMBER) AS 

 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VEHI('fields') SELECT 'fields' FROM vehicle WHERE vehicle_no=num; 
 END dispvehicle; 
 /
```

Comment: Or `insert into vehi select * from` as the OP was trying to do. While naming each field separately is indeed a best practice, it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variable `vehi` as `rowtype`, even if `vehi` is a defined object in database, by variable definition like i mentioned, there wil raise no problem and it will accept `vehi` as a `local` variable, instead of an `object` of db. By the way `is` clause is missing in the definition of procedure.

So, you may try this successfully :

```
create or replace procedure dispvehicle(num in number) is
  vehi vehicle%rowtype;
begin
  select * into vehi from vehicle where vehicle_no=num;
end;
```

Comment: Two points here: (1) The OP's assignment, apparently, was to have the data inserted into the new table, one way or another - not just to load it into a local variable. (2) Naming a local variable the same as a table in the database is not a best practice - it will lead to confusion (and, likely, to bugs).

Comment: @mathguy The OP asks about the problem, and i just replied for this.

Comment: The OP didn't state the question very clearly - but notice that he defined a new table in the database, named `vehi`, and did NOT define a variable by that name in the procedure. Presumably (but it is, indeed, only a presumption) the assignment was to insert rows in the new table; selecting into a local variable, only to not use it for anything in the rest of the procedure, is pretty pointless.

Comment: @mathguy i evaluated from the different point of view that even if there is a created object with `vehi`, he can define a variable with the same name locally which overrides that. Perhaps, he wanted to learn this manner ...